# Linking statically OpenSSL crypto library in CMake

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, openssl

I want to statically link the libraries listed below:

```
set_target_properties(exec PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_START_STATIC 1)
set_target_properties(exec PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})

find_library(SODIUM_LIB libsodium.a REQUIRED)
find_library(SSL_LIB libssl.a REQUIRED)
find_library(CRYPTO_LIB libcrypto.a REQUIRED)
find_library(DL_LIB libdl.a REQUIRED)

message(${SODIUM_LIB})
message(${SSL_LIB})
message(${CRYPTO_LIB})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

target_link_libraries(
    exec
    ${SODIUM_LIB}
    ${SSL_LIB}
    ${CRYPTO_LIB}
    ${DL_LIB}
```

I do not want to add `-static` to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`, because in that case everything is linked static. CMake finds the static libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
```

and it seems that everything is linked statically except `libcrypto`:

```
readelf -d exec
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.0.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

How can I link `libcrypto` statically to my executable?

Comment: have you checked you actually find the right library? Also it may help to optionally define the path where the static library is to be found.

Answer (score 25):

The CMake documentation starting with version 3.4 on the [FindOpenSSL page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/FindOpenSSL.html) says:

> Set OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS to TRUE to look for static libraries.

(Assuming if they are found they will be used)

Example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(Foo)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

Comment: As stated by @Tsyvarev in the comments, `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` is an hint in finding libraries and should prepend `find_package(OpenSSL)`. Verified in `FindOpenSSL.cmake` source, edited accordingly.

Comment: "should prepend" -> "should come before". Prepend is the opposite of append. In any case, things don't prepend things, let alone themselved. Things _are prepended_ to other things.

Comment: @rubenvb Both of the examples on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prepend use *prepend* in the active voice.

Comment: @Omegastick Yes, active voice when A is prepending B to C, not when D "is prepending" _itself_ to E.

Comment: bickering aside, "precede" seems more clear to me. "prepend" almost implies concatenation