# Static linking of OpenSSL Crypto in CMake

Tags: cmake, openssl, static-linking

I need to make a cross-compiled OpenSSL for a MIPS device. I've tried following the documentation. Set `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` to true and set `target_link_libraries` to the library files you need.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
compileAsC99()

if(NOT ${use_http})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "program being generated without HTTP support")
endif()

set(program_c_files
    ...
)

set(program_h_files
    ...
)

include_directories(...)

add_executable(program ${program_c_files} ${program_h_files})

set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
#target_link_libraries(program OpenSSL::Crypto)
target_link_libraries(program /home/program/mips/lib/libssl.so.1.1)
target_link_libraries(program /home/program/mips/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
```

It compiles fine without warnings, but checking the resulting binary tells me that it's still shared library.

readelf -d program:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x1bc contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libssl.so.1.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.1]
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [/home/program/mips/lib]
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Already looked at [Linking statically OpenSSL crypto library in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477940/linking-statically-openssl-crypto-library-in-cmake) but it didn't tell me anything new.

EDIT 2: Updated the CMakeLists.txt file according to the reply:
CMakeLists.txt:

```
compileAsC99()

if(NOT ${use_http})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "program being generated without HTTP support")
endif()

set(program_c_files
    ...
)

set(program_h_files
    ...
)

include_directories(...)

add_executable(program ${program_c_files} ${program_h_files})

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
message("OPENSSL FOUND!")
endif()
target_link_libraries(program OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

Output:

```
-- IoT Client SDK Version = 1.2.11
-- Provisioning client OFF
-- target architecture: GENERIC
-- Cross compiling not using pkg-config
-- Found CURL: /home/program/mips/lib/libcurl.a (found version "7.63.0")
-- Found CURL: /home/program/mips/lib/libcurl.a
-- target architecture: GENERIC
-- target architecture: GENERIC
-- target architecture: GENERIC
-- target architecture: GENERIC
-- iothub architecture: GENERIC
OPENSSL FOUND!
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

EDIT PROSPERITY: 
If you, future people, run into the `undefined reference to dlopen`, I added the following to my `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
target_link_libraries(program ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting to TRUE, variable `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` forces `find_package(OpenSSL)` to search the static library. So this variable works only with that call, and if you use its results:

```
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(program OpenSSL::Crypto)
```

---

If you have already executed `cmake` without setting of `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS`, then you need to remove CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` under build directory) before new attempt. Otherwise, already found (shared!) libraries will be used and no re-search will be performed.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It seems to find the correct `ssl` and `crypto` library files according to the build log, but `readelf`still reports that those are shared. Tried deleting the ´cmake` folder entirely and rebuilding everything without any change. Is there another flag somewhere that needs to be set somewhere perhaps?

Comment: "It seems to find the correct `ssl` and `crypto` library files according to the build log" - please, show that part of log, where one can find whether libraries are static or shared. Also, as you have in your code `target_link_libraries(program OpenSSL::Crypto)`, you don't use `target_link_libraries(program /home/program/mips/lib/libssl.so.1.1)`, do you?

Comment: Updated my post with output and revised `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: The output contains static library for `libcurl`, but your problem is with `libssl` and `libcrypto`. Note, that in your updated code you use [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655094/3440745) on related question, not mine. I have added comments for that answer why it is suspicious.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that `.a` were static libraries. That makes more sense then. Updated my toolchain file to use the `SET (OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)` and now the output says `Found OpenSSL: /home/program/mips/lib/libcrypto.a (found version "1.1.1a")`. Fails with a lot of undefined references now, but at least it seems to be using the static library instead.

Comment: *Shared* library contain list of all libraries it depends from. When link with a shared library, the linker automatically link with all these dependent libraries. But *static* libraries doesn't contain such list. When link with a static `libcrypto.a` you need to *explicitely* link with all libraries it depends from.

Comment: How do I link the libraries it requies? find_library?

Comment: *Linking* is always performed with `target_link_libraries`. But for *searching* the libraries (instead of hardcoding paths to them) you may use any available way. If the library supports `find_package(XXX)`, then use that command. If the library can be found with `pkg-config` command-line utility, then use [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindPkgConfig.html). If the library supports none mechanism for search it, then resort to `find_library`.