# Link OpenSSL statically in cmake_list

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, static-linking

I am coding an encryption program for educational purposes.
I am using openssl as the encryption library. The problem is that I want to produce an executable that can run on systems without openssl installed. Therefor I need to link openssl statically.
I am using a cmake_list for building.

As soon as I add the flag `OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS` `TRUE` I get linker errors...
I have tried building openssl from sources and passing it to the find_package command but this still gives me a linker error for all openssl headers.

```
'''c++
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(encryption_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/ssl)
set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    include/)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    stdc++fs
    OpenSSL::SSL)
'''
```

The errors are like:

```
undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_init'
```

So many thanks for any help or ideas how I can fix this!

Comment: When use 3d-party **static** libraries, it is your responsibility to link with all other libraries they need. This is because such infomation isn't contained in the *static* library, as opposite to a *dynamic* library. Undefined function is defined in the `pthread` library, so you need to link with that library. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620918/cmake-and-libpthread) about using pthreads in CMake.

Comment: oh thanks i did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem with an answer given in
[Static linking of OpenSSL Crypto in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165172/static-linking-of-openssl-crypto-in-cmake?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The hint `target_link_libraries(program ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})` solved my linker issues, just in case anyone else struggels with this.