# How to correctly specify CMakeLists file

Tags: android, cmake

I am trying to add openssl to android studio project.

I have the open ssl binaries in the project as follows:

[image]

I put the following into my **CMakeLists.txt** file

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
set(import-lib-location ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../libs)
include_directories(include/)

add_library(crypto SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(crypto
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${import-lib-location}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libcrypto.a)

add_library(ssl STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(ssl
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${import-lib-location}/${ANDROID_ABI}/libssl.a)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        openssl

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        openssl.c)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        openssl

        ssl
        crypto
        )

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.



# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
        log-lib

        # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
        # you want CMake to locate.
        log)

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        openssl

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib})
```

However, I am not able to build the code, as it keeps throwing errors to the effect of:

```
    [2/2] Linking C shared library /Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libopenssl.so
FAILED: /Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libopenssl.so 
: && /Users/lena/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi27 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/lena/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/lena/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.1.5948944/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fno-addrsig -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libopenssl.so -o /Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libopenssl.so CMakeFiles/openssl.dir/openssl.c.o  /Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libssl.a /Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a -llog -latomic -lm && :
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_compress_block: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_expand_block: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/armeabi-v7a/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Where did you get those static libraries from? Were they also built using the Android NDK?

Comment: You assign `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property for `crypto` library target, so you probably want to make this target `IMPORTED`: `add_library(crypto STATIC IMPORTED)`. BTW, you make the same for ssl library, but make it incorrectly too. Proper way is: `add_library(ssl STATIC IMPORTED)`.

Comment: @Michael they were built according to the instructions in https://github.com/leenjewel/openssl_for_ios_and_android/

Comment: @Tsyvarev I did that, and edited my Q, can you look please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48655094/549372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you get are because of a missing [zlib dependency](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#zlib_compression).
Add the following:

```
find_library(zlib-lib z)
target_link_libraries(openssl ${zlib-lib})
```

Or better yet, add `zlib-lib` to the `ssl` target's `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property:

```
find_library(zlib-lib z)
set_property(TARGET ssl APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${zlib-lib})
```

Comment: CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
zlib-lib
linked by target "openssl" in directory /openssl/app/src/main/cpp

Comment: how do i try your second approach? what does it mean `add zlib-lib to the ssl target's INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES property.`

Comment: Fixed typo and added the second approach

Comment: ninja: error: 'openssl/app/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libssl.a', needed by 'openssl/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libopenssl.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: Please inspect the generated ninja file. The output in your question uses the correct path to `libssl.a`, so something must have changed in the meantime.

Comment: where is the ninja file ?

Comment: somewhere under "/Users/lena/Dev/testprojects/open/openssl/app/build", I presume?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203253/discussion-between-lena-bru-and-botje).

Comment: can we please talk in the chat? i really need to figure this out